# Got Unknown data after PPS content

Tags: mp4, file-format

I try to write a script to get AVC configuration from mp4 container.
But there are some bytes after PPScontent!
In my script i suppose PPScontent is the end of the AvcV box,so next bytes should be the header of next box.
What are those bytes after PPScontent? the following is the file struct.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzMn4.png)

Comment: We can't tell you why your code isn't working, because you've not posted your code. You may find it helpful to spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mcve], to learn how the site works and what our expectations are before you start posting. It will make your experiences here much better.

Comment: thank you for so quick reply.but if you check the image,i think its not the matter with the code.just what are those bytes after PPS content.they are not the next box's header they are in avcc box.

Comment: Is the surrounding box `avc1`? If so, Then it's a bug in whatever software is generating the extra data.

Comment: @szatmary Yes,this file was created by VLC.
Thank you,i dont know much about the H264 format.I try to create the file again.there are not those extra data anymore.